# xamarin.forms: visual studio freezes while deploying to emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin.forms. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition. The first build and deploy to the emulator works fine. Now I make a simple change to the application title and attempt to re-deploy the application to the emulator.

Now whenever I try to re-deploy the app to the emulator either the build process hangs for ever, either visual studio freezes for ever. Any help would very much appreciated as I have spent many hours and I could not find a solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this problem for any one facing this problem:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64088/android-emulator-opens-but-project-does-not-deploy-and-start

(See the user named Grazi)